# PHP: Change specific line of txt File with ID

Tags: php, include, explode

im searching for almost 2 hours for an solution for my problem.
i have a text file with a few lines:

```
Title1|||Content1
Title2|||Content2
Title3|||Content3
```

But now i want to change 2 specific line, for example Title2||Content2
i will send the id via url. so i know which line, but i wan't search via title or content which line php should change.

i have found this code:

```
    $daten = file('../news.txt');        
$fp = fopen('../news.txt', 'w');            
foreach ($daten as $zeile){
    $felder = explode('|||', $zeile);        
    if (!strcmp($felder[0], 'auto3')){    
        $felder[1] = 'xx';                
        $zeile = implode('-', $felder);    
    }
    fwrite($fp, $zeile);               
}
fclose($fp);
```

But how to change for expample

Title2|||Title3

of

$zeile[1]

which i get via 
edit.php?id=1 ??

Comment: sry, i meant:

But how to change for expample

Title2|||Content2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if I haven't understood your question correctly, don't kill me if my answer is wrong. In your case $daten is an array that contains the lines of the file "news.txt". $_GET['id'] will provide the offset that is required to edit the array.

```
$daten = file('../news.txt');
$fp = fopen('../news.txt', 'w');
$zeile = explode('|||', $daten[intval($_GET['id'])]);
$zeile[0] = 'ASD';//change Title1
$zeile[1] = 'FGH'."\r\n";//change Content1
$daten[intval($_GET['id'])] = implode('|||', $zeile);
fwrite($fp, implode('', $daten));
```

Comment: YES, you are my man :)) never read of [intval($_GET['id'])] :O
I had to remove the \r\n becaus of extra lines..
the only problem is that the script writes an extra '|||' so the next line will look like: |||title1|||content1

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot to remove something. The last line should be fwrite($fp, implode('', $daten)); Please do not forget to "accept" my answer ;)

Comment: Thank you, will try it :) would also rate it up but i don't have enough reputation ;)

Comment: so, looks good, but now there is a very last big problem.
if i change the first line, everything works great - but if i want to change for example line 2 or 3 of the txt file, the updated variables will overwrite the first line. :(